# Svelte how to update a count based on what value is in a select box

Tags: html, css, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

Im using the following code and trying to get a count based on what option is selected, and updating live as you de select or re select a value. The drop down is for an attendance screen where you have counts for how many students are 'Present', 'Online' 'Absent' etc

Code below - I need a way to update the counts in the student-count class from what is selected in the custom-select

```
<form id="roles-form" action="#">
  <div class="student-count">
  <p>Present:{presentCount}</p>
  <p>Absent:{absentCount}</p>
  <p>Other:{otherCount}</p>
  <p>Online:{onlineCount}</p>
</div>
  <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Photo</th>
          <th>Surname</th>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Attendance</th>
          <th>Today's Attendance</th>
        </tr>
      <tbody id="role-table-body">
          {#each studentsList as student}
            <tr>
              <td><img src={student.picture.thumbnail} alt={student.name.first} style="width:50%;"></td> 
              <td>{student.name.last}</td> 
              <td>{student.name.first}</td>
              <td class= "attendance-value">
                <div class="square green" title= "Monday 15th of October">P</div>
                <div class="square red" title= "Wednesday 19th of October">A</div>
                <div class="square green" title= "Monday 25th of October">P</div>
                <div class="square green" title= "Wednesday 30th of October">O</div>
                <div class="square red" title= "Monday 5th of November">A</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="custom-select">
                  <select on:change={() => onlineCount++}>
                    {#each attendanceOptions as answers}
                      <option value={answers}>
                        {@debug answers}
                        {answers.text}
                      </option>
                    {/each}
                  </select>        
                  <span>&#10003;</span>
                  <span>&#10540;</span>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          {/each}
      </tbody>
    </table>

</form>
```

Comment: Try to avoid reimplementing standard functionality. If you really have to, make sure it is actually accessible (which can be a lot of work and easy to get wrong), see e.g. [guidelines on a combo-box](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/example-index/combobox/combobox-select-only.html). Ideally, use an existing implementation that already takes care of all that.

Comment: (It looks like your "custom select" is currently not very custom, so if you keep the `<select>` element, you do not have to do any additional work to make it accessible.)

Comment: Also, buttons should be buttons, so the checkmark and cross should be wrapped in a `<button>` element (`type=button` to prevent submitting the `form`).

Comment: @H.B. do you have a suggestion on how I can figure out this count problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the selected value on the student object or a separate object (depending on whether mutating the student list is acceptable in this context) by using `bind:value` on the `select` element.

The counts then can get generated via a reactive statement (`$:` ).

Example with separate object:

```js
let attendanceOptions = [
    { value: 'present', text: 'Present' },
    { value: 'absent', text: 'Absent' },
    { value: 'online', text: 'Online' },
    { value: 'other', text: 'Other' },
];

let attendances = {};
$: attendancesValues = Object.values(attendances);
$: presentCount = attendancesValues.filter(s => s == 'present').length;
$: absentCount = attendancesValues.filter(s => s == 'absent').length;
$: onlineCount = attendancesValues.filter(s => s == 'online').length;
$: otherCount = attendancesValues.filter(s => s == 'other').length;
```

```html
<!-- Assuming the students have an 'id' -->
<select bind:value={attendances[student.id]}>
  {#each attendanceOptions as answer}
    <option value={answer.value}>
      {answer.text}
    </option>
  {/each}
</select>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/6e6a762f008143a48d88643c10fa88d1?version=3.52.0)

Comment: my students are generated from this
onMount(async () => {
  const res = await fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=20')
  const resResponse = await res.json()
  studentsList = resResponse.results;
})

Comment: What would I use instead of student.id?

Comment: You could use the index of the `{#each}` (see its docs). Though you should have *some* way to uniquely identify students.

Comment: I have got it working, except now every box value changes when you select the first one. I have 20 students currently and if I change the 1st value it changes all the boxes value which I dont want happening

Comment: Fully working now, thanks for the help

Comment: Great! You can accept an answer by clicking the checkmark outline to its side.